# Magento2 css from module isn't loading

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, css, head

I want to load a custom css file for the admin panel from a custom module folder.

My layout xml file looks like this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::test.css" />
    </head> 
</page>
```

I've also tried

```
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css" />
</head>
```

I tried putting the file in

```
Vendor/Module/view/web/css/test.css
```

or

```
Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/test.css
```

After each I cleared the cache, the page cache and the pub/static folder.

The css file is not loading. Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Assuming that your module is enabled, try running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: that worked... so php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
is not enough.... do I have to run setup:upgrade every time i add new js or css file to a module ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `bin/magento setup:upgrade` always seem to solve my issue

Comment: ok, 10x. one more question. When I write in a js file from a certain module, I always have to clear pub/static and regenerate full static content so I can check what I've done, how can I escape that on development mode ?

Comment: According to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html development mode should not cache those files

Comment: yeah, but changes do not take effect unless i clear pub/static and run static-content-deploy again. And I've checked, I am in developer mode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your module is enabled and configured correctly

Run

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```